# How to invalidate reactive observer using code?

Tags: shiny

Given pseduo-like code:

```
dateRange <- reactive({
    input$select_dates #action button

    save_selected_date_range()
    isolate(input$dateRange)
})


customerId <- reactive({
    #check if customer has saved date range if so trigger
    saved_info <- saved_preferences(input$customerId)
    if(nrow(saved_info) > 0) {
      flog.info(saved_info)
      updateDateRangeInput(session, "dateRange", start = saved_info$start, end = saved_info$start)
    }

    input$customerId
})
```

The scenario:

**Inputs:** 
A selected date range and customer selector. The date range is registered when the action button is pressed.

**Desired Action:** 
We would like the ability to load saved date ranges if available when a customer is picked.

**Question:**
How do I trigger the input$select_dates as if the action button was pushed? Something like [invalidateLater](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/invalidateLater.html) without the timer would be nice. Or if there is a manual way to mark or flag the input$select_dates as invalidated.

Answer (score 13):

Define a reactive value

`rv <- reactiveValues( v = 0)`

put it inside your reactive expression

```
dateRange <- reactive({
    rv$v
    input$select_dates #action button

    save_selected_date_range()
    isolate(input$dateRange)
})
```

just change the value of `rv$v` (like `rv$v <- rv$v + 1`) in any part of your code and the `dateRage` expression will be invalidated.